# multiple javascript date picker

Tags: javascript

I am building and web page in php and all the content is laid out like so ..

```
<div>
<form>
<input type='text' id='datepick' />
</form>
</div>

<div>
<form>
<input type='text' id='datepick' />
</form>
</div>

<div>
<form>
<input type='text' id='datepick' />
</form>
</div>
```

Its layout is  a bit more complex really but basically the problem I am having is that the datepick id calls the datpick function but it only works on the first input and ignores the rest. I cant give them there own ids all the inputs must be called the same.

This is the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        new datepickr('datepick', {
            'dateFormat': 'd-m-Y'
        });
</script>
```

Can any one tell me how to make the datepick work on all input fields.

Thanks in advance, I am proper struggling with this one ....

Comment: What datepicker library are you using for this?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`!  Give them all the same `class` instead.  Also, what is `datepickr`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not sure, but I'm thinking https://code.google.com/p/datepickr/

Comment: 1) IDs should be unique. 2) What `DatePicker` plugin are you using?

Comment: Why must they all be "called the same"? Give them the same `name` if you have to, but the `id` **has** to be unique, especially for this library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or just change the id to class like mentioned:

```
<script>    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
```

works fine.

Comment: The question isn't referring to the jQuery UI datepicker widget

Comment: @TimothyRadzikowski This works if you're using jQuery, jQuery UI, and are trying to use the `datepicker` widget. None of that is specified in the question, nor is it even remotely close to the syntax: `new datepickr('datepick', { 'dateFormat': 'd-m-Y' });` is clearly not targeting the jQuery UI datepicker. They're most likely using https://code.google.com/p/datepickr/

Comment: THankyou all for your help and suggestions. I Just changed all the ids to classes and used jquery datepicker instead of the datpicker i was usiung .

Answer (score 3):

Look at the example here on how to use it:

http://www.joshsalverda.com/sandbox/date_pick/datepickr.html (from https://code.google.com/p/datepickr/)

You *must* give them all their own id.

HTML spec requires `id` to be unique but it will still render the page for you. Which element will be found when you look for a non-unique id in undefined. It might be the first, it might be the last, you might get an error.